# Excel Email Database Replace function

Tags: excel, email, excel-2008

I have an Excel database of email addresses and names. I need to extract the domain name from the email address, and put it into a new column.

i.e:

```
col a: joeschmoe@email.com
col b: www.email.com
```

Where `col a` is what I currently have, and `col b` is my goal. I basically need to delete anything at and before the `@` symbol, and replace with `www.`.

Is there any way I can do this in Excel in an automated process? I am using Excel 2008 for Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this in column B1 and drag all the way down:

```
="www." & MID(A1,FIND("@",A1)+1,LEN(A1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try copying ColumnA to ColumnB, selecting ColumnB and then [Replace](http://www.uwec.edu/help/excel07/ws-find-m.htm) with:

Find what: `*@`
Replace with: `www.`

<kbd>Replace All</kbd>.